# Passing @RequestParam from @ActionMapping to @RenderMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, portlet

I am working with Spring MVC portlets on Liferay and I am looking for a way to pass the RequestParam from the ActionRequest to the RenderRequest.
Here are the signature of my 2 function.

```
    @ActionMapping(params="action=bookmark_fiche")
    public void bookmarkFicheRef(@RequestParam long ficheId, ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response){

        ...
        response.setRenderParameter("action", "view_fiche");
    }

    @RenderMapping (params="action=view_fiche")
    public String showFiche(@RequestParam long ficheId, ModelMap model, RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response){
        ...
    }
```

The render function showFiche is use by other link and work fine when using

```
<portlet:renderURL var="rowURL" >
    <portlet:param name="action" value="view_fiche" />
    <portlet:param name="ficheId" value="${fiche.ficheId}" />
</portlet:renderURL>
```

but if I use

```
<portlet:actionURL var="boookmarkFicheRefURL">
    <portlet:param name="action" value="bookmark_fiche" />
    <portlet:param name="ficheId" value="${SEARCH_CONTAINER_RESULT_ROW.object.ficheId}" />
</portlet:actionURL>
```

the action phase successes but render phase fail with error:

```
09:24:39,132 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-5][render_portlet_jsp:154] org.springframework.web.portlet.bind.MissingPortletRequestParameterException: Required long parameter 'ficheId' is not present
```

`response.setAttribute("ficheId", Long.toString(ficheId));` does'nt work either ...

Do a way exist to transfert the param without modifying the render method?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand if this is what you want but if you want to call the render method from the action method, together with:

```
response.setRenderParameter("action", "view_fiche");
```

which you correctly added (sets the render parameter "action"), you should add the ficheId parameter

```
response.setRenderParameter("ficheId", Long.toString(ficheId));
```

expected by the render method as well.